# PreRegistrationHandler not failing on Task error code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, stormpath

I am trying to implement validation on a custom data attribute through the `PreRegistrationHandler`. This works great when it passes validation.

However, when it does not, it creates the account anyway. When validation does not pass, I return a Task result code of one which should make it fail.

```
PreRegistrationHandler = (context, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var passesvalidation = DoesPassValidation(context); // evals to false
            if (!passesvalidation)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(1); //should fail and not create account, but does anyway
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0); // passes
        }
```

Is there an undocumented return code that I should be using? I've checked here: https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/aspnet/latest/registration.html#pre-registration-handler

Comment: Great question, btw. Sorry it's not available yet; this is on my roadmap. PRs are always accepted, too. :)

Comment: FYI: Updated my answer now that this feature has been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality works as of [version 0.9.0](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-aspnet/releases/tag/0.9.0) of the Stormpath ASP.NET plugin.

The syntax for failing validation inside of the `PreRegistrationHandler` is:

```
PreRegistrationHandler = (context, cancellationToken) =>
{
    var passesvalidation = DoesPassValidation(context); // evals to false
    if (!passesvalidation)
    {
        context.Result = new PreRegistrationResult()
        {
            Success = false,
            ErrorMessage = "No way, José!" // optional validation message
        };

        return Task.FromResult(1); // returned value doesn't matter
    }

    return Task.FromResult(0); // without setting context.Result, success is assumed
}
```